# Horizontal Radio Buttons

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

How do you create horizontal radio buttons with Formly?  I have created this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/guyebinifa/edit?html,js,output) to show the radio button that I have created.  But for the life of me I cannot make the radio buttons appear horizontally.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to overwrite the bootstrap default template and create your own with the label defining class radio-inline. see:

[jsbin with new template](http://jsbin.com/vepidatola/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add `"inline":true` to you `templateOptions`

Example:

```
"key": "default-radio-985",
"type": "radio",
"templateOptions": {
  "inline": true,
  "label": "Radio",
  "valueProp": "value",
  "keyProp": "name",
  "options": [
    {
      "name": "Value One",
      "value": "value one"
    },
    {
      "name": "Value Two",
      "value": "value two"
    }
  ]
}
```